# Is it possible to set the ringtone file(name) for a phone number in a contact using codes?

Tags: iphone

There is a ringtone file 'myringtone.m4r'.

Is it possible to set this ringtone file(name) as a phone number response ringtone in a contact using objective-c codes?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't programmatically change the user's ringtone.

This will lead to overriding the user's prefernces by some third party application.

Comment: This will lead to overriding the user's prefernces by some third party application.

Comment: Thanks, and What does this mean?

Comment: It means that you will not pass the apple application aproval

Answer (score 0):

Ive heard it can be done, but apple will reject any app that does this kind of behavior.